# Display whole image with same ratio using fresco library

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android. I'm using fresco to display images from my server to my app but I'm only able to display it with fixed height also fresco does not allow wrap_content. Is there a way i could do this using fresco?

Answer (score 0):

http://frescolib.org/docs/using-drawees-xml.html#fixing-the-aspect-ratio answers your question, I think.

Comment: Yeah i did it using aspect ratio. I calculated the images ratio at the server side and send it with the image, then i used setaspectratio () to set there heights